# analytic formula for eigenvalues of symmetric matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a project I am working on, I would like to find symmetric matrices depending on a parameter for which the eigenvalues can be written analytically and the corresponding eigenvectors vary as the elements of the matrix vary.

I did research on the internet and there are some classes of matrices for which the eigenvalues are known:

1) Circulant matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)

2) specific kind of tridiagonal matrices: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/070695411

but the problem is that the eigenvectors stay constant so it is not appropriate for my case. Can anyone give me a parametrized matrix with analytic formula for the eigenvalues for which the eigenvector also depend on the parameter?

Thanks in advance,
Koen

Comment: You could stick to $2\times 2$ matrices; or do you need the size of the matrix to be a free parameter as well?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for matrices of dimensions n with n as large as I want